# Probability that vertex is isolated

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

I just read about random graphs and the $G(n,p)$ model which has the following probabilistic properties. The probability space is given by $\Omega:=\{G \in \text{Graph} \ | \ G \ \text{has} \ n \ \text{vertices}\}$, with the sigma algebra $\text{P}(\Omega)$ and probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ given on a Graph with $n$ vertices by $$\mathbb{P}(G)=p^m(1-p)^{\binom{n}{2}-m}.$$ Now, I want to calculate the probability that a random graph has an isolated vertex, meaning a vertex with no neighbours. What does this event look like as a set? Is it given by the set $A:=\{G \in \Omega \ | \ G \ \text{has an isolated vertex} \}$ or how can I write this as a subset of $\Omega?$ I know that the probability is given by $(1-p)^{n-1}$ that a given vertex $v$ is isolated and therefore that $n (1-p)^{n-1}$ is the probability that it has any isolated vertex. However, why are those the probabilities? I cant seem to compute those. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Certainly $A := \{G \in \Omega \mid G \text{ has an isolated vertex} \}$ is a description of the set of all graphs in the probability space which have an isolated vertex.

To do calculations in this probability space, it helps to have a different description. It is a product space: each pair of vertices independently is adjacent with probability $p$. This gives us $$\mathbb{P}(\{G\})=p^m(1-p)^{\binom{n}{2}-m}$$ for a graph $G \in \Omega$ with $m$ edges, since we want $m$ specific pairs to be adjacent ($m$ factors of $p$) and the other $\binom n2 - m$ pairs not to be adjacent ($\binom n2 - m$ factors of $1-p$).

With this interpretation, we can show that $(1-p)^{n-1}$ is the probability that a specific vertex $v$ is isolated. There are $n-1$ other vertices; for each of them, we don't want to get an edge to $v$, so we multiply together $n-1$ factors of $1-p$.

It is **not true** that $n(1-p)^{n-1}$ is the probability that any vertex is isolated. This would be the probability if the events $A_v := \{G \in \Omega \mid v \text{ is isolated in }G\}$ were disjoint: two of them could not happen at the same time. In that case, $\mathbb P(A)$ would be the sum $\sum_v \mathbb P(A_v) = n (1-p)^{n-1}$.

However, these events are not disjoint: for example, in the empty graph with $0$ edges, all of them occur simultaneously.

Instead, $n(1-p)^{n-1}$ is an **upper bound** on $\mathbb P(A)$: the union bound. This says, in general, that if you have a bunch of events, the probability of at least one of them happening is *at most* the sum of their probabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain, why this alternative discription is valid formally? I have not read about that one at all unfortunately. Furthermore, when one is asked to compute the probability that a random graph has an isolated vertex, is this then the probability of the $A$ I gave? This feels weird in a way,  because $A$ contains multiple graphs in general, not a fixed but random one. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: If a formal explanation would take too long, I would also appreciate a reference if you have any.

Comment: (1) The argument I gave in the answer is the justification that the alternative description is valid: it gives the same probability for every singleton event $\{G\}$, and the probabilities of the singleton events determine all other probabilities.

Comment: (2) Yes: the probability that a random graph has an isolated vertex is the probability of the set $A$. You should think of it this way: all events are sets of outcomes, and $A$ is the set of outcomes that would make "there is an isolated vertex" happen. Let me use bold letters for random objects for a moment: if $\mathbf G$ is a graph randomly chosen from this model, then $\mathbf G$ has an isolated vertex if and only if $\mathbf G \in A$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I will need to read about product spaces again and think about that specific case. However, your answer did help me alot already and will even more once I reread the important things.

Comment: i) There are 2 things that confuse me right now. $(1)$ What are the sets that form the product space? Do you take $V$ twice and then let a graph be a subset of $V \times V$? $(2)$ Lets fix a vertex $v$. If I want to compute the probability that $v$ is isolated, I need to compute the probability of the set of graphs of $\Omega$ that satisfy that $v$ is isolated in this graph. Again, those are many. You then write, that we dont want to have a vertex to the other $n-1$ vertices for any graph. Thus, for a fixed graph, I know that I don't want $n-1$ of those edges.

Comment: ii) However, since I need to fix a graph here and there are many others in the set that I need to compute the probability of, I don't see how this gives me the correct probability. Furthermore, the number of edges that do occur also don't seem to play a role. Im sorry if this is something simple I am just not seeing, but I really am confused, since I don't seem to see what is going on.

Comment: (1) For each edge $vw$, we have a probability space only about that edge, in which $vw$ is present with probability $p$ and absent with probability $1-p$. We are taking the product of those $\binom n2$ probability spaces. You do not have to think about this in term of product spaces if you don't want to. (2) The point is that your event $A$ is determined by the status of the $n-1$ edges incident on $v$, the others are irrelevant. So we can compute its probability by only looking at those $n-1$ edge.

Comment: After thinking about the probability for some more time, I unfortunately still dont see it. My problem is the following. If I want to compute the probability of a particular vertex being isolated, then I have several graphs in that set in general. Writing this as a disjoint union of single graphs, I have that the empty graph satisfies the condition, thus having probability $(1-p)^{\binom{n}{2}}$ for that one. I then have to add the probabilities of the others, e.g. a graph with only one edge that is not $v$ and so on. I cant see how that leaves me with the probability $(1-p)^{n-1}.$

Comment: Perhaps there is a more formal way to see why that is indeed the probability perhaps there is not. But I don't see it with the explanation you provided, I am sorry.

Comment: I am telling you *not* to use the formula you started with, and you keep saying "well, if I use the formula I started with, I don't see how to get the answer".

Comment: I misunderstood you then, I thought you saying I dont have to use the product space means I can also see it with my approach. But the problem remains, even if I use the product space, I dont see how other edges are irrelevant, since they determine the exponent of the $p$ for any graph.

Comment: Each of them contributes a factor of $p + (1-p) = 1$, since you don't care if they're there or not for the event "vertex $v$ is isolated".

Comment: Thanks for your patience, but I still dont think I see it completely. I will try to think about it some more times with your approach, but I think its pointless to steal any more of your time. Maybe I just wont get it.